# macros from plain TeX fail to work in xelatex

Tags: xetex, tex-core, plain-tex

I find some macros from plain TeX fail to work in XeLaTeX. The following MWE for example. Why?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{showframe}
\geometry{left=1cm,right=1cm,top=1cm,bottom=1cm}

\begin{document}
$$\eqalign{
a+b &= c+d \cr
x &= w + y + z \cr
m + n + o + p &= q \cr
}$$
\end{document}
```

```
ERROR: Undefined control sequence.

--- TeX said ---
l.11 $$\eqalign
               {
```

Comment: `\eqalign` is a plain tex macro so not defined in latex (any flavour of latex, not just xelatex) `$$` is a tex primitive which also should not be used in latex (although it does not give an error)

Comment: Is there any way to use macros of plain Tex in LaTex?

Comment: you need to define them, latex does not include plain tex sources, `\usepackage{plain}` defines most of them but really there is no reason to ever do this, the latex constructs are in general better and certainly work better in combination with other latex features. note that even when latex and plain tex commands have the same name, they typically do not have the same definition.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Some* plain TeX commands also work in LaTeX, but there's no general rule and, generally, it's best to avoid them anyway.

The LaTeX manual explicitly mentions that `\eqalign` is not defined in LaTeX (page 233). The manual says to use `eqnarray`, but that's to be considered superseded by the `amsmath` environments.

Also `$$` should never be used in LaTeX.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{showframe}
\geometry{left=1cm,right=1cm,top=1cm,bottom=1cm}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
  a+b &= c+d \\
  x   &= w + y + z \\
  m + n + o + p &= q
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Note that a trailing `\\` should *not* be used.

[image]